# Error During Print

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

There are a three public variable

```
public var objPrintJob:FlexPrintJob;
public var objPrintTemplate:canvas;
```

**Fn1:**

```
objPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();
if (objPrintJob.start() != true)
{
        printCount--;
        return;
}
```

Starting the PrintJob;

**Fn2:**

```
Am adding the Object and calling send for the Print

objPrintJob.addObject(objPrintTemplate, FlexPrintJobScaleType.SHOW_ALL);
objPrintJob.send();
```

During Run

It Throws the Error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mx.printing::FlexPrintJob/addObject()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\printing\FlexPrintJob.as:252]
    at org.dckap.mafcote.views.mediators::WorkAreaMediator/parseXML()[F:\MafcoteMGP\MafcoteMGP\src\org\dckap\mafcote\views\mediators\WorkAreaMediator.as:3243]
    at org.dckap.mafcote.views.mediators::WorkAreaMediator/onSaveTemplateWithCredits()[F:\MafcoteMGP\MafcoteMGP\src\org\dckap\mafcote\views\mediators\WorkAreaMediator.as:2896]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:12266]
    at org.dckap.mafcote.views::CreditsShowPanel/okButtonClickHandler()[F:\MafcoteMGP\MafcoteMGP\src\org\dckap\mafcote\views\CreditsShowPanel.mxml:41]
    at org.dckap.mafcote.views::CreditsShowPanel/__btnOk_click()[F:\MafcoteMGP\MafcoteMGP\src\org\dckap\mafcote\views\CreditsShowPanel.mxml:159]
```

Need Help For This..

```
                }
```

Comment: You should really improve your examples when asking a question.  Also, you never instantiated your Canvas (why are you using canvas in a Flex 4 app anyways?).

Comment: I initated the object and with it has a child in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your support I found out my solution.
Thank U all.

The object does not seems to be null.
I did one mistake that is i didn't added the object as a child anywhere else.
so the addObject() in print requires the systemManager.
which will be null if i didn't add as a child.

Thank You for your support

Answer (score 2):

This has to be that your objPrintTemplate object is null. The stack trace in your error shows that it's erroring in `FlexPrintJob/addObject()`, which means it made it into that method but did not complete executing the method. Since the only parameters you're sending to it are your object reference and a constant value, the object must be null.

Comment: I initated the object and with it has a child in it.

Comment: I don't think there's much more that can be figured out from what you've posted. I suggest you add a breakpoint just before the addObject() method and debug your app to check those object references and make sure they really are not null.